# By using com.mapquest.mapping.maps.MapView in android xml, raise console error. Error: Channel is unrecoverable broken and will be disposed

Tags: android, xml, mapquest

I am integrating mapqeust map view in android, I need to integrate in relative layout. I am using com.mapquest.mapping.maps.MapViews in my android xml layout. When, I am launching my application it get crash also not showing any error message. Only shows following line in console.
**"Channel is unrecoverable broken and will be disposed"**
My code snippet are following:

```
<com.mapquest.mapping.maps.MapView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/mapQuestMapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:mapquest_app_key="@string/mapquestKey"
        tools:context="com.mcruiseon.buseeta.MapActivity" />
```

Answer (score 0):

After spending one day research, I found above question's answer. In MapActivity.java file, we need to add following lines in activity life cycle methods.

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;

    import com.mapquest.mapping.MapQuestAccountManager;
    import com.mapquest.mapping.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
    import com.mapquest.mapping.maps.MapboxMap;
    import com.mapquest.mapping.maps.MapView;

    public class MapActivity extends Activity{
        private MapView mapQuestMapView = null;
        private MapboxMap mapBoxMap = null;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            MapQuestAccountManager.start(getApplicationContext());

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
            mapQuestMapView = findViewById(R.id.mapQuestMapView);
            mapQuestMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            mapQuestMapView.getMapAsync((MapboxMap mapboxMap) -> {
                   mapBoxMap = mapboxMap;
               });
        }

        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            mapQuestMapView.onResume();
        }


        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            mapQuestMapView.onDestroy();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            mapQuestMapView.onPause();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
            mapQuestMapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        }
    }
```

Reference link are: https://developer.mapquest.com/documentation/android-sdk/